# Marquee nodeValue update dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

I have a basic problem where I couldn't update the marquee nodeValue dynamically. The following is the HTML Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="update.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" id="marquee"></marquee>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the update.js is

```
document.getElementById("marquee").firstChild.nodeValue = "New Text";
document.getElementById("marquee").start();
```

Can anyone tell me how to update the Marquee from other javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `marquee` element does not have a `firstChild`. Your code will work as it is if you give it a default value:

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" id="marquee">Default</marquee>
```

Alternatively, you can set its [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) (or `innerText` where appropriate):

```
document.getElementById("marquee").textContent = "New Text";
```

---

*But `marquee`... really?! I'd suggest looking at alternative solutions.*

Comment: Alternative Solutions ? Actually I am going to display the News Contents in the Marquee. Which will be retrieved every 10/15 mins.